# How to make the default copy paste menu on textfield rather than translucent flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want default android menu rather than this. How can it be done?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by default android menu

Comment: https://imgtr.ee/image/qaOyF like this

Comment: please you [edit] your question to include the code

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `surface` property in `ColorScheme` inside `ThemeData`

```
theme: ThemeData(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme(
   surface: Colors.transparent,
 ) 
)
```